# BIND9 with mysql DataBase as zone store

Tags: bind, port-forwarding

I have implemented a DNS server on AWS. I am using BIND9 as DNS service which accesses its zones from a MySQL database. Each one, BIND9, MySQL are running correctly, but the service doesn't answer any request or test.

For example, I used the following command:

> $ dig @localhost mydnsdomain.com

And then, it answers with a zone from MySQL database.
 But if I use:

> $ dig mydnsdomain.com

It shows:

> "no servers could be reached"

I am not an expert on DNS servers, what is happening? I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: No delegation in place?

Comment: Please post your configuration files for bind9 so we can determine where how you are attempting to configure BIND9 to read your zones from MySQL. Also post the schema for your Database. Another thing to include would be the output from running:
named -V on the EC2 instance running BIND9. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Without having your bind config... my first guess would be that the allow-query { } option is set to  or has defaulted to only allow 127.0.0.1. But then again, that would probably result in some kind of "denied" message from dig.

Take a look at your /etc/resolv.conf file and make sure there are name servers defined there.

---

In order to get everything working externally for the world, you will need to ensure that your domain registrar has 'glue' records to point to your dns server and that your dns server allows queries from any ip address.

If this is only for internal use, every machine that needs to know about the existence of "mydnsdomain.com" must point all dns queries to your bind server.

Comment: Thank you Daniel Widrick. I solved my issue making a glue record.